# ORDER BY in DENSE_RANK()

Tags: sql

I want to use `DENSE_RANK()` to partition Week Numbers, and ordered by id
and it work fine.

But i have some cases that i have a id that have a duration in tow week numbers,
its gave him another id than the first because of the order by.

this is the result :

```
CardID      WeekN       RowNum

2467        1           1   
**2481      1           *2***   
2468        2           1   
2473        2           2   
2482        2           3   
**2481      2           *4***   
2473        3           1   
2482        3           2   
2481        3           3
```

My Query for RowNum is:

```
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Lng_CardWWeek  ORDER BY Duration , CardID  Desc) as RowNum
```

How i should fix it?

Comment: Show us the table data and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() 
OVER (PARTITION BY Lng_CardWWeek  ORDER BY Duration , CardID  Desc) AS RowNum
FROM <<tablename>> AS <<name>> 
[WHERE <<condtion>>]
GROUP BY CardID
ORDER BY RowNum
```

you have to use SELECT, to specify that u are trying to get some data from a table. Further u have to include the name of the table.

If u simply will list those elements with the same CardID in following rows, use the ORDER BY clause outside the OVER clause as well.

Try an outer GROUP BY to get only one line per CardID.

Comment: sorry, but u only posted the dense rank part. So I thought you are missing SELECT and FROM clauses. If the problem is somewhere else, please provide an example what you are trying to get

Comment: it woulb be helpful if u can post the source data to select on